# log4j RollingRandomAccessFile rollover when event received

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

Just a quick question as I couldn't find anything concrete in the log4j documentation.  Does the RollingRandomAccessFile behave in the same way as the RollingFileAppender in that it only checks for a rollover when it writes events, or does the difference in buffering affect this?

Here are a few snippets from my config:

```
<Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
</Policies>
```

with a file pattern of:

```
filePattern="${sys:logging.path}${sys:logging.file}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rollover behavior of RollingRandomAccessFile is the same as RollingFileAppender.

Note that both Appenders accept a CronTriggeringPolicy that gives a time based rollover trigger.